# React Native :Strange Behaviour backgroundColor in ListView running in iphone6Plus

Tags: ios, listview, react-native

I meet some trouble while using React Native's ListView,the strange behaviour is set the row's backgroundColor will perform different result between iPhone6 and iPhone6plus

My Code in render() function

```
render: function(){
  return (
    <View>
      <ListView
        scrollEnabled={false}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
        dataSource={dataSource.cloneWithRows(values)}
        initialListSize={values.length}
        pageSize={3}
        scrollRenderAheadDistance={500}
        renderRow={this._renderRow}
      />
    </View>
  );
},
```

styles:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
list: {
  flexDirection: 'row',
  flexWrap: 'wrap',
},
row: {
  backgroundColor:'white',
  width:w.width/3,
  height: w.width/3,
  borderWidth: 0.5,
  borderColor: '#f3f3f3',
  alignItems: 'center',
}});
```

running in iPhone6,it's OK!
[image]

but running in iPhone6Plus
[image]

Comment: In your styles you use `w.width` what is `w`? The screen sizes are different between 6 and 6Plus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should't set `borderWidth` as an float number with iPhone6Plus.

Try replace `borderWidth: 0.5` with `borderWidth: 1`.

As to why, sorry, i don't know the principle of deep.

I just know `PixelRatio.get() === 3` in iPhone6Plus, you should set the width as a number like

`width * PixelRatio.get() = [an integer]`